# Logical Error With SQLite Query

Tags: android, sqlite, android-contentprovider

So I'm making an application for my class where the user submits a form and the data is recorded in a database. Right now I'm trying to implement a check that checks if the username the user is trying to pick exists in the database or not. Here's my code right now:

```
//Username duplicate check                                                                                                                       
String mSelection = MyContentProvider.COLUMN_USERNAME + "= ?";
String[] mSelectionArgs = new String[] { "Username" };
String[] mProjection = new String[]{MyContentProvider.COLUMN_USERNAME};
mCursor = getContentResolver().query(MyContentProvider.CONTENT_URI,
                                     mProjection,
                                     mSelection,
                                     mSelectionArgs, 
                                     null);
if (mCursor.moveToFirst()){
if (userName.getText().toString().equals(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.COLUMN_USERNAME)))){
    submitCheck = false;
    userName.setHint("Username taken");
}
```

}
    mCursor.close();

When this is run, the if statement garners an error. Here's the logcat:

```
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907): android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 0
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:400)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:50)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.connor.black.HomeWork2Activity$1.onClick(HomeWork2Activity.java:132)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
06-24 00:56:55.125: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Here's a little bit of my content provider for some context:

```
public class MyContentProvider extends ContentProvider{
public final static String DBNAME = "FormStorage";
public static final String AUTHORITY = "com.connor.black.provider";
public final static String TABLE_NAMESTABLE = "formstable";
private static UriMatcher sUriMatcher;

public final static String COLUMN_FIRSTNAME = "FirstName";
public final static String COLUMN_LASTNAME = "LastName";
public final static String COLUMN_PHONE = "PhoneNumber";
public final static String COLUMN_EMAIL = "Email";
public final static String COLUMN_USERNAME = "Username";
public final static String COLUMN_PASSWORD = "Password";
public final static String COLUMN_GENDER = "Gender";
public final static String COLUMN_COUNTRY = "Country";
public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://com.connor.black.provider/" + TABLE_NAMESTABLE);


private static final String SQL_CREATE_MAIN = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAMESTABLE + "("+"_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "+
                                                                    "FirstName TEXT, " +
                                                                    "LastName TEXT, " +
                                                                    "PhoneNumber TEXT, " +
                                                                    "Email TEXT, " +
                                                                    "Username TEXT, " +
                                                                    "Password TEXT, " +
                                                                    "Gender TEXT, " +
                                                                    "Country TEXT)";
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should **not** hard code the column index values directly into your code. This is because,

1. It's poor design.
2. It makes your project difficult to maintain (i.e. if you add a column to your table later, it is possible that the column's integer could change, thus breaking your code).
3. There is no way to know for certain if `0` corresponds to the username column. The integer value is assigned by an internal library that manages your SQLite database... you should **never** rely on internal libraries as the Android team could change the implementation at any time.

I suggest you change your code to the following:

```
int userCol = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.USERNAME_COLUMN);
mCursor.getString(userCol);
```

Comment: I think I've found something. I got a null pointer exception when I tried this `final int userCol = mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.USERNAME_COLUMN);`

Comment: First of all, I updated my answer. Second of all... that's a problem, and it probably means that the `USERNAME_COLUMN` does not exist. Try uninstalling and then re-installing your application (or go to "Settings --> Applications --> [your application] --> Clear data"). Then test it out. If it still doesn't work, then let me know.

Comment: I cleared the data, ran again, and I'm still getting a null pointer exception

Comment: Wait, sorry. You did pass it `MyContentProvider.COLUMN_USERNAME` right? (not `USERNAME_COLUMN`)

Comment: I've changed my check to this `if (userName.getText().toString().equals(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.COLUMN_USERNAME))))` but this reared some new errors. I'm going to update my question

Comment: Yes I passed `MyContentProvider.COLUMN_USERNAME`

Comment: Either `userName`, `userName.getText()`, `userName.getText().toString()`, or `mCursor` is `null`. Figure out which one is `null` and update your question with the information.

Comment: @ConnorBlack, you removed the `mCursor.moveToFirst()` call? This call was important... put it back :)

Comment: I put it back and still the user is able to enter a username that exists.

Comment: Are you getting an error? Update your question so that it is 100% up to date... I can't guess what problem you are having unless everything is updated and I know exactly what is going on. Also, for the love of God break up this line of code into multiple lines: `userName.getText().toString().equals(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.COLUMN_USERNAME)))`. You are making it incredibly difficult on yourself to debug your code as there is no way to tell which part of the line is giving you a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12958/discussion-between-alex-lockwood-and-connor-black)

Comment: I'm not getting a force close error, only a logical error. I'm able to submit the form twice with the same username, which should not happen.

Answer (score 0):

It looks 0th is _ID in your table try it with 5th index..........

Comment: ohh sorry user name is 5th index. Better to try getColumnIndex(MyContentProvider.USERNAME_COLUMN); as Alex said as per standered ..........

Comment: As far as I am concerned, you should not even be concerned with what the actual values are, as they are subject to change at any time. The actual integer values should be 100% abstracted out of your code.